# Vuejs - vue3-easy-data-table

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, vue.js, css-tables

Im working on a project in vuejs that uses "vue3-easy-data-table" Im following the style recommendations on this page.

https://hc200ok.github.io/vue3-easy-data-table-doc/features/style-customization.html

when I try to use

--easy-table-body-even-row-font-color: #fff;
--easy-table-body-even-row-background-color: #4c5d7a;

It does not take change the background color of the even rows. Even if I add !important it doesn't make a difference and if you click on the edit with code Sandbox it doesn't work there either.

Any idea how I could get this to show a different color for even rows as it does in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if you set the **`table-class-name`** and **`alternating`** attribute to your custom style.

like in the example there is this code:

```
<EasyDataTable
  theme-color="#1d90ff"
  table-class-name="customize-table" // important
  header-text-direction="center"
  body-text-direction="center"
  alternating // important
/>
```

```
.customize-table {
  --easy-table-body-even-row-font-color: #fff;
  --easy-table-body-even-row-background-color: #4c5d7a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I was missing alternating it worked once I added that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to follow the [docs](https://hc200ok.github.io/vue3-easy-data-table-doc/css-variables.html) on using `--easy-table-body-even-...` CSS properties which states:

> Don't forget to use with [alternating](https://hc200ok.github.io/vue3-easy-data-table-doc/features/alternating.html) feature

```js
<EasyDataTable
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    table-class-name="customize-table"
    alternating
/>
```

```css
.customize-table {
  --easy-table-body-even-row-font-color: #fff;
  --easy-table-body-even-row-background-color: #4c5d7a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I was missing alternating it worked once I added that.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me since I added `import 'vue3-easy-data-table/dist/style.css';`.

Full code:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import EasyDataTable, { Header } from "vue3-easy-data-table";
import "vue3-easy-data-table/dist/style.css";
//...
</script>

<template>
  <ClientOnly>
    <EasyDataTable
      theme-color="#1d90ff"
      table-class-name="customize-table"
      header-text-direction="center"
      body-text-direction="center"
      alternating
      :headers="headers"
      :items="taskStore.tasks"
    >

    </EasyDataTable>
  </ClientOnly>
</template>

<style>
.customize-table {
  --easy-table-border: 1px solid #445269;
  --easy-table-row-border: 1px solid #445269;

  --easy-table-header-font-size: 14px;
  --easy-table-header-height: 50px;
  --easy-table-header-font-color: #c1cad4;
  --easy-table-header-background-color: #2d3a4f;

  --easy-table-header-item-padding: 10px 15px;

  --easy-table-body-even-row-font-color: #fff;
  --easy-table-body-even-row-background-color: #4c5d7a;

  --easy-table-body-row-font-color: #c0c7d2;
  --easy-table-body-row-background-color: #2d3a4f;
  --easy-table-body-row-height: 50px;
  --easy-table-body-row-font-size: 14px;

  --easy-table-body-row-hover-font-color: #2d3a4f;
  --easy-table-body-row-hover-background-color: #eee;

  --easy-table-body-item-padding: 10px 15px;

  --easy-table-footer-background-color: #2d3a4f;
  --easy-table-footer-font-color: #c0c7d2;
  --easy-table-footer-font-size: 14px;
  --easy-table-footer-padding: 0px 10px;
  --easy-table-footer-height: 50px;

  --easy-table-rows-per-page-selector-width: 70px;
  --easy-table-rows-per-page-selector-option-padding: 10px;
  --easy-table-rows-per-page-selector-z-index: 1;

  --easy-table-scrollbar-track-color: #2d3a4f;
  --easy-table-scrollbar-color: #2d3a4f;
  --easy-table-scrollbar-thumb-color: #4c5d7a;
  --easy-table-scrollbar-corner-color: #2d3a4f;

  --easy-table-loading-mask-background-color: #2d3a4f;
}
</style>
```